# Deleting Objects Before Export from Maya Causes .PSK to Crash UDK on Import

Tags: udk, unreal, maya

I'm using Maya 2008 Complete and 03/11 build of UDK as well as 07/10 build (haven't got around to installing newer version on other computer). I am using ActorX to export.

I have a character that I have rigged and animated (I'm not using UDK rigs).

**Here was my process:**

- Early on in the process, I had other objects skinned to the character's skeleton.
- I hid those objects while weighting the character
- I decided later that I wanted to delete them.
- I tested my .psk in both UDK builds with those objects hidden and noticed that they still showed up (in UDK)
- So, I went back into Maya, detached the skin on those objects and deleted history, then deleted them.
- I then re-exported my .psk and now when I try and import, udk crashes.

Here are my input/output connections for one of the objects before detaching the skin.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoDdv.jpg

**Here is my log:**

```
0002.77] Log: >>>>>>>>>>>>>> Initial startup: 2.77s <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
[0002.81] Cmd: MODE MAPEXT=udk
[0002.87] SourceControl: Source Control disabled in GAMEEditorUserSettings.ini.  [SourceControl] has Disabled=False
[0005.61] Log: TIMER ALL OF INIT : [5.028131]
[0070.42] Log: FactoryCreateBinary: SkeletalMesh with SkeletalMeshFactory (0 0 Z:\websterProject2\EXPORTTESTING\SK_snailMesh01.PSK)
[0070.42] Log:  * Skeletal skin VPoints            : 812
[0070.42] Log:  * Skeletal skin VVertices          : 1166
[0070.42] Log:  * Skeletal skin VTriangles         : 1596
[0070.42] Log:  * Skeletal skin VMaterials         : 1
[0070.42] Log:  * Skeletal skin VBones             : 73
[0070.42] Log:  * Skeletal skin VRawBoneInfluences : 1520
[0070.42] Log:  * Skeletal skin VertexColors          : 0
[0070.42] Log:  * Skeletal skin Num Tex Coords    : 1
[0070.42] Log:  Mesh material not found among currently loaded ones: lambert3SG
[0070.42] Log: Bones digested - 73  Depth of hierarchy - 15
[0070.49] Critical: appError called: Assertion failed: Wedges.Num() == WedgeInfluenceIndices.Num() [File:c:\depot\UnrealEngine3\Development\Src\Engine\Src\UnSkeletalTools.cpp] [Line: 301]
Stack: Address = 0x402228f9 (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\UDK.exe]
Address = 0x40924bb1 (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\UDK.exe]
Address = 0x412bfbc8 (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\UDK.exe]
Address = 0x401a178d (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\UDK.exe]
Address = 0x412964a4 (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\UDK.exe]
Address = 0x412823a4 (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\UDK.exe]
Address = 0x983633   (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\wxmsw28u_vc_custom_64.dll]
Address = 0x983d73   (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\wxmsw28u_vc_custom_64.dll]
Address = 0x983e30   (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\wxmsw28u_vc_custom_64.dll]
Address = 0x800a34c6 (filename not found) [in C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\Binaries\Win64\wxmsw28u_core_vc_custom_64.dll]
Address = 0x800aec65 (filename not found) [in C
```

I would like to know why deleting these objects is causing the .psk to crash on import and how I can fix it.

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure if this was something to do with UDK or ActorX but the problem ended up being some extra inputs on the character in Maya.

I had a blend shape on the character that must have had a connection with those objects. I deleted all inputs except for the skin cluster on the character and everything works fine now.